# Eeevee & Lookdev all materials bright white

Tags: rendering

I'm on mac os 10.11.6, trying 2.8 beta. System is old Mac pro with quadro fx 4800 but is compatible with opengl 3.3.

All materials are rendering bright white. Any setting to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Same issue on linux ubuntu 18.04.2. Always after suspending or hibernating. Restarting blender solves the issue to me.